# TideSDK: is there a way to style menus?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, tidesdk

I was working with TidSDK's menus...

```
var menu2 = Ti.UI.createMenu();

//Create menu items
var subMenu1 = menu2.addItem('',function(){history.back();},'back.png');

Ti.UI.currentWindow.setMenu(menu2);
```

And I was wondering: is there a way to style them? Like height, width, background, icon-size, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately: no. The native menus are bound to the systems style. If a user changes the theme of his OS, the native menus in a TideSDK app will change their look, too.

If you want to have full styleable window/context menus, you will have to create them with HTML/CSS and control them via JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, it is not a problem on my pages, but what if I show a GoogleMaps page for ex? I think I can't do something like Ti.UI.currentWindow.setMenu(MyHtmlMenu)...

Comment: No, that won't work for sure, but you can build a menu that stays on the top border of the window with css position:fixed.

Comment: Update: I've found a solution for custom menus that works even on external pages (e.g. goole, youtube, stackoverflow,...). I don't know, it might be of interest?